# Search for \w chars ending with parenthesis excluding other signs

Tags: search

Hello I have this text:

```
public static Type Name = new Type();
public static Type NameX() {}
```

If I search:

```
/public static \(.\{-}\) \(\w\+\)(
```

I get both lines selected until the `(`, but I expect the first one should not be.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I thought that searching for `\w` means alphanumeric not including `=` or spaces, but when I add the `(`, it's like the `\w\+` converts to `.*`

gVim version 9.0 patches 1-1778 on Windows 10

[image: search and selected text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do:

```
/public static \(\S\+\) \(\w\+\)(
```

or maybe more readable using super magic:

```
/\vpublic static (\S+) (\w+)\(
```

What I believe happen on your test is that `.\{-}` is eating all the symbols you don't want (i.e: `=`,  ).

Before you enter the parenthesis it does not because of its non-greedy nature (`\{-}`). It doesn't have to eat to find the next space. But has soon as you add the `(` it has too to match and so it does.

You can analyse that by converting your search into a substituion:

```
:s/public static \(.\{-}\) \(\w\+\)(/1:\1, 2:\2/
```

Comment: Or even `… ([^=]+) (\w+)\(`